# C++ Merge-Sort Algorithm with Subsequence Sorting

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, computer-science, mergesort

The idea is the following:

we want to create a merge-sort algorithm that takes a sequence length 'n' and divides this n-length into subsequences such that you have n subsequences that are then sorted.

**Example:**

```
    n = length 4 
    Array = {2, 9, 4, 1}
```

then you get something like:

```
    Sub1 = {2} Sub2 = {9} Sub3 = {4} Sub4 = {1}
```

This will sort the subsequences by comparing them and then merge them together to form one sequence again. (Illustrated below)

> Sequence -> split into Subsequences -> Subsequences compared -> Merged
>   into sorted sequence.

The basics behind it is a recursive merge-sort, but instead of dividing the sequence by 2, we want to divide by the length of the array.

I created a working merge-sort that takes a user-inputed length of the list (however generates random values of the list) and sorts. However I get stuck when it comes down to sorting by the length. In my code I have 3 functions and the user-input is given in the main (the length). How do I change this such that I can use the user-input as my division factor for my sort?

Note: I don't want a code, but more of an explanation on how to approach this. I tried a couple times with moving and merging my functions, but I haven't gotten anywhere.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: to the best of my understanding, you are looking for something called the [Bottom-up implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation) of merge-sort

Comment: It's a bottom up merge sort. Note that most "real world" implementations of merge sort, such as C++ STL std::stable_sort are some variation of bottom up merge sort. I'm not sure why top down merge sort is so popular in classrooms and some web sites.